# All wp-json routes suddenly return 404

Tags: rest-api, api

I'm having a problem, where all API routes on a site are now returning a 404 error. This has been working for quite some time but just recently started doing this. I'm not sure if it was from an automatic update or what.

`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` or any other post type, always returns 404 now. What could cause this? It's not even a custom route or anything, just the standard built-in routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was really weird. I just went to the Permalink settings and clicked Save without changing anything. That somehow fixed it.